# using AbpApplicationFactory.Create overwrites IConfiguration

Tags: abp

When using Abp to run a HostedService the IConfiguration created in the main method gets overwritten when using AbpApplicationFactory.Create

The main methods uses the default Microsoft implementation to connect to the AzureKeyvault:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => logging.ClearProviders())
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<DbMigratorHostedService>();
            })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();

                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                    keyVaultClient,
                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

For now I am using the default DbMigrator that is added when creating an abp module:

```cs
public class DbMigratorHostedService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

        public DbMigratorHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
        {
            _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var application = AbpApplicationFactory.Create<MyDbMigratorModule>(options =>
            {
                options.UseAutofac();
                options.Services.AddLogging(c => c.AddSerilog());
            });

            application.Initialize();

            await application
                .ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<MyDbMigrationService>()
                .MigrateAsync();

            application.Shutdown();

            _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I can see that the AbpApplicationFactory.Create method also has options. However this doesn't have anything to configure the configuration. Why is the application scope not using the same IConfiguration from outside the scope ? Outside the scope i got 6 configuration providers including the key vault configuration and inside the scope there are only 2 missing the Keyvault one.

Am I missing something here ?

I also tried to get rid of the application scope, then i get the right configuration. However then I can't call the initialize method on the application and I can't use a startup class since it isn't a web application.

Answer (score -1):

You are right. The startup template is not designed to handle such cases. I created an issue to fix it: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/5006

For now, you can replace the configuration with your custom built one:

[image: Replace configuration]

I din't try it, but this will also probably work (and it is exactly what you want):

1. inject IConfiguration to the hosted service.
2. Pass it to the ReplaceConfiguration.

[image]

Comment: I implemented a better solution for the console application startup template https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/templates/console You can check it and apply same for your application until it is released.